# Build my own 'JQuery object' containing specific elements

Tags: jquery

How can I build my own 'JQuery object' containing specific elements? For example;

```
function getSelection() {
    var ele1 = $('<p></p>').appendTo('body');
    var ele2 = $('<p></p>').prependTo('html');
    return $([ele1, ele2]); // how to return a 'JQuery object' containing ele1 and ele2?
}
```

The above doesn't work for the following code that uses chaining which is my ultimate goal.

```
console.log('font', getSelection().first().css('font-family');
```

I have to do something like:

```
console.log('font', getSelection().first()[0].css('font-family');
```

So how can I build my own JQuery object of specific elements so that I can then interact with it as a JQuery object and not an 'array wrapped in a jquery object'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not very far from the kingdom. Use [.add() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
return ele1.add( ele2[0] ); //or ele1.add( ele2 )
```

See demo below:

```js
function getSelection() {
    var ele1 = $('<p></p>').appendTo('body');
    var ele2 = $('<p></p>').prependTo('html');
    return ele1.add(ele2[0]); // how to return a 'JQuery object' containing ele1 and ele2?
}

console.log('font', getSelection().first().css('font-family') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```